# useDelimiter not working as expected

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
in = new Scanner(klant);
in.useDelimiter(",");
while(in.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(in.next());
}
```

In the variable klant is this line:

```
12127,Preusterink,M.F.,,15-03-1903,8191 QK,147
```

I expect this as output

```
12127
Preusterink
M.F.

15-03-1903
8191 QK
```

But I'm getting

```
12127
Preusterink
M.F.

15-03-1903
8191 
QK
```

It seems the whitespace is still a delimiter even though I set it to ",". Anyone can clear this up for me?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. I could include a short but complete program to show it *not* behaving this way, but it wouldn't really be an "answer" as such.

Comment: I am getting the output as expected. It does not split on the white space. Please verify your input to the Scanner once again

Comment: Tried on another pc and it worked, odd.

Comment: Clean your workspace or delete the `.class` files, and recompile.